# Firefox grey box on when clicking links

Tags: html, css, firefox, hyperlink

I am unable to remove the grey box behind a link when it is clicked in Firefox.

I have tried using the code below which was recommended in a few different cases but it was unsuccessful.

```
a:active {
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Here is a photo of what is happening when clicking a link:

[image]

Comment: Can you show more codes, including the HTML structure & more CSS ? prefer to have a JSFiddle

Comment: A link on *any* site? Or just the one you're developing? Have you inspected the DOM in Firebug? Which CSS classes are applying? What do they do?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

```
a:focus{
background: none;
}
```